# Vb.net: Get md5 hashcode result in integer form

Tags: vb.net, hash, md5

My problem is to generate md5 hash code of input string and return result in integer form, because I need to do arithmetic operation on result.

Comment: What is your issue? Converting the string to bytes? Hashing the bytes? Converting the result to an integer? Finding the hash function? Determining the steps required?

Comment: I want to convert result to integer because I need to do modulus operation with result

Answer (score 2):

md5 is 128 bit so you would need to use `BigInteger`

```
Dim str = "Test"
Dim md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()
Dim hash = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str))
Dim i = New System.Numerics.BigInteger(hash)
```

And apply a modulus operation

```
Dim result = i Mod 90329434 'Returns 30719684
```

Comment: I would suggest `UTF8` instead of `ASCII` - unless you're sure that the input is ASCII-only, which I wouldn't generally assume.

Comment: @JoeEnos Yes, always use the appropriate encoding for the input.

Comment: well I have tried this code but it is not working. when I am applying arithmetic operation (modulus) on result,I m getting error "specific cast is not valid". What should I do now?

Comment: This code absolutely works, what you do later might not however. What do you do? It seems you are trying to cast `BigInteger` to something else?

Comment: I have written your code as it is but still I m getting error. Plus if i try to print the result i.e Msgbox(i), its give error i.e "Argument prompt cannot be converted to Type string". I am using visual basic 2010. where I am wrong?

Comment: If I m writing your whole code and write command Msgbox(i) to view result, it is giving error "Argument prompt cannot be converted to Type string". I am getting same error when I m trying to print modulus operation result i.e Msgbox(result) so where I am wrong?

Comment: @irum Do: `Msgbox(result.ToString())`